# Terraform: Error: Not enough list items: vpc_config.0.subnet_ids requires 1 item minimum, but config has only 0 declared

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am trying to launch an EKS cluster  in  AWS using VPC, subnets and security groups  and deploy them to my test environment. The code in my development environment and for my test environment are identical and  i have created a test.tfvars file to deploy to test env.

When i run  **terraform plan -var-file=test.tfvars** I get the following erorr:

```
Error: Not enough list items
│ 
│   with module.eks.aws_eks_cluster.aws_eks,
│   on modules/eks/main.tf line 118, in resource "aws_eks_cluster" "aws_eks":
│  118:     subnet_ids              = var.private_subnets
│ 
│ Attribute vpc_config.0.subnet_ids requires 1 item minimum, but config has only 0 declared.
```

Below is the eks.tf file

```
module "eks" {
  source = "./modules/eks"

  assume_role_policy = var.assume_role_policy_eks
  ssh_key_name       = var.ssh_key_eks

  # Private Subnet 1/2
  private_subnets = data.aws_subnets.subnet_ids_private.ids
  env             = var.env
  aws_account_id  = var.aws_account_id
  region          = var.region

  desirednode    = 2
  maxnode        = 4
  minnode        = 2
 
}
```

test.tfvars file

```
env = "test"
access_logs_bucket = "s3bucket"
subnet_ids = ["subnet-03", "subnet-03"]
public_subnet_id = ["subnet-05", "subnet-07"]
```

EKS module main.tf file

```
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids              = var.private_subnets
    endpoint_public_access  = false
    endpoint_private_access = true
  }
```

my eks variables.tf file:

```
variable "private_subnets" {}
variable "instance_types" {}
variable "capacity_type" {}
variable "minnode" {}
variable "maxnode" {}
variable "desirednode" {}
variable "env" {}
variable "assume_role_policy" {}
variable "aws_account_id" {}
variable "region" {}
variable "ssh_key_name" {}
```

The above code work using my variables.tf file and deploys to another environment. I am facing this issue when deploying to test env using the test.tfvars file

I have also checked my data source for both the VPC data.aws_vpcs.vpc_list and Subnets data.aws_subnets.subnet_ids_private.ids. However when i run terraform state it is not able to pick the VPC ID:

```
# data.aws_subnets.subnet_ids_private:
data "aws_subnets" "subnet_ids_private" {
    id   = "eu-west-2"
    ids  = []
    tags = {
        "Type" = "Private"
    }

    filter {
        name   = "vpc-id"
        values = []
    }
}
```

Comment: Your tfvars file has only `subnet_ids` and `public_subnet_ids` but you are referencing `var.private_subnets`: `subnet_ids              = var.private_subnets`.

Comment: how can i define the var.private_subnets in tfvars file ?. In my EKS variables.tf the private_subnets has been defined.

could you please help me on that

Comment: I have no idea if you have any private subnets or not.

Comment: so the subnet_ids are the private_subnets that i have. In the eks.tf the private subnets have been linked via:   private_subnets = data.aws_subnets.subnet_ids_private.ids

What changes can  i make in my terraform to resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you add the data source to the question as well?

Comment: we dont have a data source file,  the subnets ID have been provided in test.tfvars  that are being used by the eks cluster

Comment: What is this line then doing: `private_subnets = data.aws_subnets.subnet_ids_private.ids`?

Comment: I have added it to the question. i have found the problem which is that the VPC ID is not being picked at all. Event though the VPC exists in my AWS Account

Answer (score 0):

After lots of digging into my code, as my VPC ID was not picked. it was due to the vpc_name not being provided in my test.tfvars file that was in the aws console. When the code was being run it was not able to find the VPC eventhough it had existed.

once i added the vpc_name variable along with its value. it fixed my problem

```
vpc_name = ["my_vpc_name"]
```

Comment: where did you add this variable? I don't see a reference to `vpc_name` in the snippet shared in the question. Can you provide a bit more details?

Comment: the vpc_name was added in the test.tfvars files. if you see the snippet it is missing. 
Once i added it as variable: vpc_name = your-defined-vpc-name. i rerun the terraform command and it worked and picked up the VPC.